# Getting Syntax Error while Fetching Data from Database Using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Getting Syntax Error While i am try to retrieve data from database using JSTL and Derby Database in Netbeans please help me..

```
<body>
<sql:setDataSource
    var="myDS"
    driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
    url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/nit"
    user="root" password=" "
/>

<sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">
    SELECT * FROM NITIN;
</sql:query>

<div align="center">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>

        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${user.mobile}" /></td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance ....please ...

Comment: What is content of `Syntax Error` Nitin ? Could you post full source code of JSP file ?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: 
        SELECT * FROM NITIN;
    : Syntax error: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM NITIN; Here semi-colon ';' is not required